# Logic : steps to prove valid reasoning

Tags: logic

I am very new to this and I can't figure out the steps to prove that these reasonings are valid. Thank you for your help.

```
p
¬r
p → (q→r)
___________             
¬q
```

---

```
(¬p ∨ ¬q) → r
p
q
__________             
¬r
```

---

```
p → (r ∨ q) 
(q ∨ s ) → t
r → s
p ∨ r
__________             
t
```

Comment: How have you tried to show these? It might also help to know what textbook they came from. If you do not have a proof checker, you might try this one: http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: This is unanswerable unless you specify the rules you're allowed to use. Also please say what you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any specification about the rules, I guess all rules are allowed ?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* for 1, using [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) rules.

1) **p** --- premise

2) **¬r** --- premise

3) **p → (q → r)** --- premise

4) **q** --- assumed [a]

5) **(q → r)** --- from 1) and 3) by (→E)

6) **r** --- from 4) and 5) by (→E)

7) *contradiction* with 2) and 6)

> 8) **¬q** --- from 4) and 7), by (⊥E), discharging assumption [a].

---

Regarding 2, check it with truth table.

---

Regarding 3, use "nested" (∨E).